# Which is efficient? Flutter StreamBuilder Widget vs Stream.Listen() with setState()

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, stream-builder

I am writing a periodic stream with duration of 1 second to show time:

```
stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  return Text(DateTime.now().toString());
}
```

Also, I can achieve the same with:

```
Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1)).listen((){
setState(){});
```

as well.

**I wonder, which approach is more efficient?**
Stream builder returning a single widget or in other cases a widget tree **every second**. While `setState()` rebuild whole app widget tree in my case. I am confused here. Please advise.

Comment: Could the [devtools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/cpu-profiler#flame-chart) have a more precise answer?

Comment: @pskink Seems now questions raises on using  `StatefulBuilder` inside `StreamBuilder` 
StreamBuilder will return StatefullBuilder each second. Also, Why we need to setState each seconds as I have already those `fields` in scope of StreamBuilder. anyways. open to discussion.

Comment: I do not want to avoid it but was curious about the performance of both method, (`StreamBuilder` vs `Stream.listen(setState(){})`) in my particular case. @ambiguous58 pointed out some useful hints below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setState` does not rebuild the whole app widget tree. Both of the methods you mentioned (StreamBuilder & Stream.listen) rebuild themselves and their descendants whenever there is a new event.

If your whole app is under a single big `build` method, then yes `setState` will trigger a rebuild of whatever `build` method it is under. If that is the case you should split up your code for performance reasons.

Your use case is actually mentioned in the [official StatefulWidget docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html).

> Push the state to the leaves. For example, if your page has a ticking clock, rather than putting the state at the top of the page and rebuilding the entire page each time the clock ticks, create a dedicated clock widget that only updates itself.

Additionally, you can always look to take advantage of the [devtools](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/cpu-profiler#flame-chart) to measure any performance differences.

Comment: So, using `StreamBuilder` seems equivalent to `dedicated clock widget` in this case. right?

Answer (score 0):

I think **First approach is more efficient** because when event comes it will only trigger the build of that stream .

however calling `setState()` will rebuild the entire widget tree of the stateful widget  .. so it costs more

Comment: I don't think that's accurate since both of the methods OP mentioned (StreamBuilder & Stream.listen) rebuild themselves and their descendants whenever there is a new event.

Comment: yes the descendants of the StreamBuilder in  First case will be rebuilt , however in the second it calling setState() will rebuild the entire widget tree even above the widget thet needs to be rebuilt

Comment: `setState` only rebuilds the `build` method it is under. So if the whole app is under a single big `build` method then yes it will be rebuilt. \*shudder\*

Comment: yes this is what  I meant exactly if you have maybe multiple stream Builders in column , then it would be better to use first method since  it will build every one according to its state.